# Storing Multidimensional Data into MySQL and Efficiently Retrieving the Children

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array

I have two tables, the `categories` tables forms the relationship between the category ID number and the title of the category. And the `category_has_child` tables forms the parent/child relationships from the `categories` table.

Example data:

```
categories    
+---------------+
| id | title    |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Tops     |
+----+----------+
| 2  | T-Shirts |
+----+----------+
| 3  | Hoodies  |
+----+----------+
| 4  | Bottoms  |
+----+----------+
| 5  | Shorts   |
+----+----------+
| 6  | Pants    |
+----+----------+
| 7  | Sale     |
+----+----------+
| 8  | Summer   |
+----+----------+


category_has_child 
+--------------------+
| parent   | child   |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 2       |
+----------+---------+
| 1        | 3       |
+----------+---------+
| 4        | 5       |
+----------+---------+
| 4        | 6       |
+----------+---------+
| 7        | 1       |
+----------+---------+
| 7        | 4       |
+----------+---------+
| 8        | 5       |
+----------+---------+
```

Would this be the most efficient way of storing a multidimensional array into a table? Is there anyway I could query this with just SQL script without many `LEFT JOIN`s?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/434ae)

Comment: It's one way of doing it. At the moment the way you have it in your fiddle, a child, say category id 7 to just pick one, could have an infinite number of parents.

Comment: You're right @Drew, I created another table to represent the absolute parent. I looked into a modified preorder tree traversal algorithm to store the data in MySQL, but that was too much for this project... So I gave up and went with a bunch of left joins. I then cache the results.

Comment: Yea, the structures get insane. Sometimes I just use stored procs and worktables. The performance isn't stellar, but simple to maintain. Simpler for the average joe to comprehend.